# App Crash on setting UITableViewCell:textLabel:text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am creating a split-view iPad application. When the user presses the bar button item in the master view, a modal is presented. This modal has a textfield and has an IBAction to pick up keyboard returns.

On keyboard returns, a new instance of my `Farm` class is created (code below). This instance is then added to an array that is stored in my delegate. I then try to reload the `MasterViewController`'s table. Upon this reload the application crashes on `cell.textLabel.text` with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

```
Farm *current = [delegate.arrayOfFarms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [current getFarmTitle];
```

If I ask the array within the delegate how many elements it has, it will indeed show the current amount, even. This is what is bizarre to me about this whole thing: the Farm instances appear to be in existence.

I have instances of AppDelegate in both my `MasterViewController` and my `NewFarmNamingView` classes. The instance in the Master is to populate the table. The instance in NewFarm is to add the newly created `Farm` to the delegate. Code below.

**Segments from class NewFarmNamingView:**

```
- (IBAction) keyboardDonePushed:(id)sender
{
    // create a Farm and add it to the delegate
    NSString *text = newFarmTextField.text;
    Farm *newFarm = [[Farm alloc] init];
    [newFarm setFarmTitle:text];
    [[delegate arrayOfFarms] addObject:newFarm];
    [newFarm release];

    NSLog(@"Added farm: %@" , text);

    // dismiss the view
    [self closeView:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize the delegate
    delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

**Segments from the class Farm**

```
- (void) setFarmTitle : (NSString *) _farmTitle
{
    farmTitle = _farmTitle;
}

- (NSString *) getFarmTitle
{
    return farmTitle;
}

// NSCoding Methods
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:farmTitle forKey:@"kFarmTitle"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    farmTitle = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"kFarmTitle"];
    return self;
}

// Initialization method
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting in the debug console?

Comment: I've updated my question with the signal received. The top of the debug stack is "objc_msgSend" right on top of "[UILabel setText:]"

Comment: Is it possible that getFarmTitle is broken?  Try wrapping it in a respondsToSelector: method.

Comment: What happens if you replace `cell.textLabel.text = [current getFarmTitle];` with `NSLog(@"%@", [current getFarmTitle)`?

Comment: @AdamW - If I try to print to console it will fail on the line containing the NSLog. I have unfortunately already tried this. :(

Comment: @CodaFi - I'm not really sure of the syntax to wrap a getting in that method. Also, under what circumstances would it be broken seeing as it only returns Farm's instance of a NSString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the runtime reference: "objc_msgsend sends a message to the receiver and expects a simple return value."

I'll bet you anything that what you're returning (if you're returning anything at all) in that class method `getTitleFarm` is returning an incorrect value.  It should be an NSString.  Be absolutely sure it is returning an NSString, and not anything else.

If you need to use the `respondsToSelector` method to see if the class is being released, try:

```
if([current respondsToSelector:@selector(getFarmTitles)])  {.    [current getFarmTitle];
} 
else {
NSLog:(@"FAILURE!!");
}
```

EDIT: maybe you are not retaining or even creating this string at all.  In it's initialization, wrap it in a `retain];` message

Comment: The `retain` function on the NSString fixed the situation. You are a life saver! :-)

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with this.